# Migrate master - detail structured table data with identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

How can I migrate master detail table data?
There is an identity in master table.

`APPOINTMENT` - Master table (With AppointmentSeq Key identity )

`APPOINTMENT_ITEM` - Detail table

I tried like below but failed.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.APPOINTMENT ([AppointmentNumber]
  ,[AppointmentDate]
  ,[AppointmentEndDate]
  ,[AppointmentTime]
  ,[AppointmentEndTime]
  ,[UserID])
SELECT [AppointmentNumber]
  ,[AppointmentDate]
  ,[AppointmentEndDate]
  ,[AppointmentTime]
  ,[AppointmentEndTime]
  ,UserID
FROM DB1.dbo.APPOINTMENT 

DECLARE @lastident AS int
SET @lastident = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO [dbo].[APPOINTMENT_ITEM]
SELECT @lastident
  ,a.AppointmentNumber
  ,a.AppointmentDate
FROM DB1.dbo.APPOINTMENT_ITEM a
INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.APPOINTMENT b
     ON a.AppointmentSEQ = b.AppointmentSEQ
```

Comment: When you say that you _tried like below but failed_, what do you mean?  Did you receive an error?

Comment: all APPOINTMENT_ITEM table data have same key value

Comment: Your insert statement into the APPOINTMENT_ITEM seems to be missing the columns you want to insert into. Just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the identity values from the old database! You just have to set `IDENTITY_INSERT`to on and you're good to go.  Hope this example will help:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ColumnA VARCHAR(100),
    ColumnB VARCHAR(100)
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Test ON

--Inserting into an identity column, which is the primary key:
INSERT INTO dbo.Test(ID,ColumnA,ColumnB) VALUES (255,'abcd','efgh')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Test OFF

SELECT * FROM dbo.Test
```